# How to change default materialize theme colour in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

I'm using rails 5.0.0.1,ruby 2.3.1 and materialize-sass gem for adding materialize css in my app,By default it is set with light-green.

How to change the default colour for whole application?

Comment: Did you check the docs https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass?

Comment: yeah the doc mentioned that we can change it like this 
@import "materialize/components/color";
$primary-color: color("grey", "darken-3") !default;
in application.sass file but it is not working for me

Comment: Hoe about posting some code?

Comment: problem solved thanks for all replying to my questions,I'll put the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved this by adding this code in my application.css.sass file

```
@import "materialize/components/color";
$primary-color: color("grey", "darken-3") !default;
@import "materialize";
```

We should import materialize after importing color.
Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried to change the ***secondary-color*** which in the [docs](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass) says is with `$secondary-color: color("yellow") !default;` but I got an error in my Rails 5 app, I needed to add a second argument to make it work fine, just like this: `$secondary-color: color("yellow", "lighten-1") !default;`. Have you had this issue too?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this later (as of 2019), the latest version of Materialize changes primary and secondary colors like this:

```
// in application.scss
@import "materialize/components/color-variables";

$primary-color: #346BA7 !default;
$secondary-color: #346BA7 !default;

@import "materialize";
```